# Woocommerce Cart Icon replaced by Question Mark

Tags: woocommerce

Your solutions to sort our complications on woocommerce is awesome and being a basic starter in this, I have actually solved lot of issues.

I have a problem with my cart icon on my site. The cart is replaced by question mark and by any measures it does not seem to go. Please guide me on how can I replace my old cart icon replace the question mark.

Please reply...

Comment: Can you give us your URL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be directed at Woocommerce support, not Stack Overflow.